# String type when using require.Equal in test

Tags: go

My code is simply:

```
func Test_DecodeLBPolicy(t *testing.T) {
    policy := decodeLBPolicy("lb:RING_HASH")
    require.Equal(t, api.RING_HASH, policy.Type)
    require.Equal(t, nil, decodeLBPolicy(""))
}
```

problem occurs at last line, the output is as below:

```
Error:   Not equal: 
         expected: <nil>(<nil>)
         actual  : *api.LBPolicy(nil)
```

then I tried to replace expected "nil" to "*api.LBPolicy(nil)" it wont compile
but when I change the require to require.Equal(t, true, decodeLBPolicy("") == nil) it passed.

Comment: Answering here because the question is closed (it should not have been, imo). For that particular error it could be resolved with `require.Nil(t, decodeLBPolicy(""))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In go, an interface of value nil isn't equal to nil. This is because it has type information associated to it, whereas the `nil` keyword has no such type. (It also has type nil).

This explains theses lines

```
    expected: <nil>(<nil>)
    actual  : *api.LBPolicy(nil)
```

You have a parameter of type `*api.LBPolicy` and of value `nil`. But you wanted a type `nil`and value `nil`.

How to fix is a bit tricky, you could make sure that `decodeLBPolicy` really return `nil` and not a interface of value nil. Or compare to a interface of the good type and with the value nil. Or use the `==` trick as you showed

More details in this post: https://glucn.medium.com/golang-an-interface-holding-a-nil-value-is-not-nil-bb151f472cc7

Comment: You are close, but the wording is imprecise, which is required when talking about language specifics. There is no nil type, a nil variable has no type. An interface can be nil, but it contains two values, both of which must be nil. nil is not a keyword, it is a predeclared-identifier used to match zero values.